# Trouble Showing After Hiding Div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide and close a window using 'Open' and 'Close' buttons.

```
$(document).on('click', '#close_box', function() {
    //$(this).parent().remove();
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
        $(this).toggle()
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#open_box', function() {
        $("body").children().show();
});
```

However, my window is not popping up again...

Here is my HTML code that is relevant:
      
        
            
                O Open

```
        <div id="sub-main">

            <div id="close_box">
                <button id="close" type="button">X Close</button>
            </div>
            ....
```

Those are the relevant div and other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use $("#div").toggleClass('hide'); 
This shows a div if it was hidden/ hides it if it was visible. Alternatively, use methods .fade in() or .fadeout()